# How to implement "short" nested vanity urls in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I understand how to create a vanity URL in Rails in order to translate
`http://mysite.com/forum/1` into `http://mysite.com/some-forum-name`

But I'd like to take it a step further and get the following working (if it is possible at all):

Instead of: 
`http://mysite.com/forum/1/board/99/thread/321`

I'd like in the first step to get to something like this: `http://mysite.com/1/99/321`

and ultimately have it like `http://mysite.com/some-forum-name/some-board-name/this-is-the-thread-subject`.

Is this possible?

Comment: Resource routing, nested routing, and shallow routing are all going to have the name of the resource in path, so if you want only ids or some-forum-name in the path you'll need to do regular routing, probably with bounded parameters.

Answer (score 5):

To have this work "nicely" with the Rails URL helpers you have to override `to_param` in your model:

```
def to_param
  permalink
end
```

Where `permalink` is generated by perhaps a `before_save`

```
before_save :set_permalink

def set_permalink
  self.permalink = title.parameterize
end
```

The reason you create a permalink is because, eventually, maybe, potentially, you'll have a title that is not URL friendly. That is where `parameterize` comes in.

Now, as for finding those posts based on what `permalink` is you can either go the easy route or the hard route.

**Easy route**

Define `to_param` slightly differently:

```
def to_param
  id.to_s + permalink
end
```

Continue using `Forum.find(params[:id])` where `params[:id]` would be something such as `1-my-awesome-forum`. Why does this still work? Well, Rails will call `to_i` on the argument passed to `find`, and calling `to_i` on that string will return simply `1`.

**Hard route**

Leave `to_param` the same. Resort to using `find_by_permalink` in your controllers, using `params[:id]` which is passed in form the routes:

```
Model.find_by_permalink(params[:id])
```

**Now for the fun part**

Now you want to take the resource out of the URL. Well, it's a Sisyphean approach. Sure you *could* stop using the routing helpers Ruby on Rails provides such as `map.resources` and define them using `map.connect` but is it really worth that much gain? What "special super powers" does it grant you? None, I'm afraid.

But still if you wanted to do that, here's a great place to start from:

```
get ':forum_id/:board_id/:topic_id', :to => "topics#show", :as => "forum_board_topic"
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [Rails Routing from the Outside In guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

Comment: that's what I've been reading, but I can't seem to grasp from the available examples and descriptions what should lead to the results I'm looking for.
Is it shallow nesting? :has_many? Or using map.connect and wildcards (which some people say you shouldn't use)...

kinda looking for a hint into the right direction here.

Answer (score 1):

maybe try something like

```
map.my_thread ':forum_id/:board_od/:thread_id.:format', :controller => 'threads', :action => 'show'
```

And then in your controller have

```
@forum = Forum.find(params[:forum_id])
@board = @forum.find(params[:board_id])
@thread = @board.find(params[:thread_id])
```

Notice that you can have that model_id be anything (the name in this case)

In your view, you can use

```
<%= link_to my_thread_path(@forum, @board, @thread) %>
```

I hope this helps