# Ruby on rails, `rails generate` with primary_key not the default integer id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, primary-key

I have a model object called 'Problem' and I want to be able to call its the 'show' action using the URL  /problems/PROBLEM_NAME.

I think the way to go about this is to change it so the primary_key is no longer the default integer id, instead I want it to be a string of letters.

I have tried to `rails g model problem problem_name:primary_key problem_text:text`
but I get the obvious error about having multiple primary keys.

Any ideas?

Comment: What you want is called a "vanity URL". I explain these here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575475/how-to-implement-short-nested-vanity-urls-in-rails/2577050#2577050

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess in your routes you have:

```
 resources :problems
```

Before the line with `resources :problems`, in your routes.rb file add this

```
 match "problems/:problem_name" => "problems#show"
```

After you added the new show route, in your problems controller, in the show action, instead of doing

```
 @problem = Problem.find(params[:id])
```

you use now

```
 @problem = Problem.find_by_name(params[:problem_name])
```

Doing it this way, you don't have to modify your database

Comment: This sounds great if it happens to work! Changing the model in the database sounded like a headache. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In generated migration, change this row:

```
create_table :problems do |t|
```

to this:

```
create_table :problems, :id => false do |t|
```

But I would recommend you using a slug as an extra column instead of text primary key...